# Robolectric getResources() throws RuntimeException (Android)

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric

I'm trying to use the Robolectric framework to create unit tests for my android projects.
I've started with an empty Android project created by the eclipse android project wizard.

In a different java project I use this code to try running a basic test:

```java
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class ApiTest {

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldHaveApplicationName() throws Exception {
        String appName = new RobolectricActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);
        assertEquals(appName, "TestDemo");
    }

    @Test
    public void testSomethingMeaningfulToMyApp() {
        fail("not implemented");
    }

}
```

I've configured everything like explained in the [Robolectric Quick Start Guide](http://pivotal.github.com/robolectric/eclipse-quick-start.html).

However, when I'm trying to run this test class I get the following exception in the line where I'm accessing the getResources() function:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Did your shadow implementation of a method throw an exception? Refer to the bottom of this stack trace.
at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.ShadowWrangler.methodInvoked(ShadowWrangler.java:86)
at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.RobolectricInternals.methodInvoked(RobolectricInternals.java:50)
at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java)
at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.shadows.ShadowContextWrapper.getResources(ShadowContextWrapper.java:40)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.ShadowWrangler.methodInvoked(ShadowWrangler.java:78)
at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.RobolectricInternals.methodInvoked(RobolectricInternals.java:50)
at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java)
at ApiTest.shouldHaveApplicationName(ApiTest.java:28)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:164)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:76)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:49)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at  sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.ShadowWrangler.methodInvoked(ShadowWrangler.java:78)
... 36 more
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at android.os.Build$VERSION.<clinit>(Build.java:95)
at android.content.res.Resources.<clinit>(Resources.java:57)
at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.shadows.ShadowApplication.getResources(ShadowApplication.java:74)
... 41 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.os.SystemProperties.<clinit>(SystemProperties.java:35)
... 44 more
```

It seems like the shadow classes are not set up properly and I didn't find a solution for this problem on google or stackoverflow.

Do you have any suggestions for me? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating a constructor for the test class that calls the Activity you're trying to test?
e.g.:

```
public class ApiTest {

    public ApiTest() {
        super(MainActivity.class);
    }

    //...the rest of your test class
}
```

I'm still learning how to do unit testing and mocking in Android myself, so I apologize in advance if this doesn't work for you.

Comment: Oh, jeeze; I just realized this question was from Dec '12, not '13 - sorry about the necro!